# DataContractSerializer unable to serialize remoted object

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, datacontractserializer

I have a remoted object that extends MarshalByRefObject. I am unable to serialize the object in its app domain itself. Reason is to persist the state to disk.

I am getting the following error:

> System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type 'System.Runtime.Remoting.ServerIdentity' cannot be serialized. Consider marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework documentation for other supported types.
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String message, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.CreateDataContract(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.GetDataContractSkipValidation(Int32 id, RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerContext.GetDataContract(RuntimeTypeHandle typeHandle, Type type)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.SerializeWithXsiType(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, RuntimeTypeHandle objectTypeHandle, Type objectType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle, Type declaredType)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerialize(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)
>      at System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializerWriteContext.InternalSerializeReference(XmlWriterDelegator xmlWriter, Object obj, Boolean isDeclaredType, Boolean writeXsiType, Int32 declaredTypeID, RuntimeTypeHandle declaredTypeHandle)

My code looks like this

```
[DataContract]
public class MyClass : MarshalByRefObject
{
    [DataMember]
    private int a;

    [DataMember]
    private bool b;

    public MyClass()
    {
        serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(MyClass));
    }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2202:Do not dispose objects multiple times")]
    public virtual void SaveToFile(string filepath)
    {
        // Method to save our object to a file.

        // If there is already a save in progress, bail (thread safety check)
        if (SaveInProgress)
        {
            return;
        }

        SaveInProgress = true;

        Stream stream = null;
        XmlWriter xw = null;
        try
        {
            stream = new FileStream(filepath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write);
            xw = XmlWriter.Create(stream, new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true, Encoding = Encoding.UTF8 });
            using (XmlDictionaryWriter writer = XmlDictionaryWriter.CreateDictionaryWriter(xw))
            {
                lock (LockObject)
                {
                    serializer.WriteObject(writer, this);
                }
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            if (stream != null)
            {
                stream.Dispose();
            }

            if (xw != null)
            {
                xw.Dispose();
            }
        }

        SaveInProgress = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is MyClass inheriting from MatshalByrefObject?

Comment: I'd suggest using a [serialization surrogate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/extending/data-contract-surrogates) in this case.

Comment: MyClass is inheriting MarshalByRefObject because I want to remote MyClass. I also need it to serialize to disk to save the state.

Comment: @dbc Am unable to create a Surrogate to ignore ServerIdentity type 
Since ServerIdentity 's protection level is not Public. public object GetObjectToSerialize(object obj, Type targetType)
        {
            // Skip serialization of a ServerIdentity
            if (obj is ServerIdentity)
            { return null; }

            return obj;
        }

Comment: @stacknheaps - what is `ServerIdentity`?  It doesn't appear anywhere in your code, which shows a `public class MyClass`.  Is `MyClass` actually private or internal?

Comment: `MarshalByRef` carries this `ServerIdentity` I believe.

Comment: @dbc `MyClass` is actually public. Somehow the DataContractSerializer is referring an `internal` type in the MarshalByRef chain. [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/remoting/serveridentity.cs)

Comment: Are you trying to serialize 1) a local object to a local file, or 2) a remote transparent proxy to a remote file, or 3) a remove transparent proxy to a local file?

Comment: @stacknheaps - because I have something that works locally.  I'm not sure it would work with remoting involved though.

Comment: I was trying to serialize remoted object locally. Apparently, it is not possible. But found a work around to make doing a MemberwiseClone(false) on the remoted object. This get rids of the identity object